# UDF call in entity framework is cached

Tags: entity-framework, entity

I am doing a test after reading an article http://blogs.msdn.com/alexj/archive/2009/08/07/tip-30-how-to-use-a-custom-store-function.aspx about udf function called. When I use a function with  objectContext.Entities.Where( t=> udf(para1, para2) == 1), here the Entities is not ObjectQuery, but an ObjectSet, the first time I call the method, it runs correctly, if I reuse the objectContext,and run it again but with different para1, para2, then the previous parameter values still cached, and the result is same as previous one, which is wrong. The sql profiler shows that both query hit the database, but the t-sql is the same. Am I missing something? And the ObjectSet does not support .where(esql_string). How to get udf working with ObjectSet?

Thanks
Fred

Comment: Have you looked at the SQL trace? That would pretty quickly tell you if the EF is doing the right thing.

Answer (score 1):

Fred,

What you describe sounds a lot like a bug in EF 4.

I'll forward to some people on the EF team to investigate.

Alex

Comment: Thanks. I am using vs.net 2010 RC, and latest ef4 bits